# Word spacing in Latex math mode

Tags: latex

I have a problem with spaces between the words in Latex math mode. I have to write text in math mode because of the work I'm doing, and I already did the job. But the words are sooo tightly closed to each other. An example is as below :

It's the code in latex:

`$>>> if ret is True:$\\`

The output is something like:
`ifretisTrue`

You see? Sooo close to each other. I need a kind of command to set the spaces between words for all the math equations throughout the entire document.

Comment: Don't use math mode for whole words, the kerning will be wrong. However what you show as an example, I rather suggest to have a look at verbatim instead of math mode. Can you show a bit more context of what you are trying to do to better judge what would be a good solution for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need a kind of settings before (begin{document}) to for example increase the whole spaces between words in math mode. Consider \ (single backslash) in $hi \ there$ that will create enough space... or \quad command... But I can't manually add these backslashes to all of my documentation. That's why I'm looking for a kind of setting to increase the space between words in math mode.

Comment: Don't try to increase the spaces inside math mode. Math mode is not suitabe for what you seem to be using it for!

Comment: If you want code, use a verbatim environment, for example `\verb|>>> if ret is True:|`. If you want to show pseudo code, have a look at various algorithm packages, but don't misuse math mode for this.

Comment: I tested verbatim... Really cool... I wish I was familiar with it before my documentation is finished.

Comment: I simply am looking for an easier way to be able to do some spaces between words in math mode... That's it, and it will make everything fine... But, if I couldn't, then I'll have to put another vast amount of time to do \begin{verbatim} \end{verbatim} s. :|

Comment: I quote @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: it seems that what is most suitable for you is using packages to write pseudo code (e.g. https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/).

Comment: @MahdiDorEmami If you have a reasonably editor, you can probably mostly automate the change from math mode to verbatim. Please do this, using math mode for this situation is the worst you can do. The missing interword spaces you notices is by far not the only problem with this. There will be also no kerning corrections and the wrong font will be used.

Answer (score 1):

In math mode LaTeX adds spacing based on mathematical rules. If you want to typeset text in math mode, use `\text{}`. In your case `$\text{>>> if ret is True:}$\\` outputs what you want if you really want to put that in math mode.

By the way, it's better to ask LaTeX related questions at https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\text{}` if you want to typeset text in math mode.

OR

If you want different spacing, LaTeX provides the following commands for use in math mode: `\;` - a thick space. `\:` - a medium space. `\,` - a thin space.